# Creating menu on symfony2.3 using render

Tags: symfony, twig

on my Admin template I've used render function to add the menu.

The controller sidebar add all links from db.

The problem is made when i want to add "current" class because i can't access of current url/controller from a render request.

```
{{ render(controller('AdminDashboardBundle:Template:sidebar')) }}
```

How I can access to all informations from the render controller (without pass a var )?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [RequestStack](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request) service has been built with Symfony 2.4. If you declare your Template controller as a service and inject RequestStack, you'll be able to use your current `render` call without passing arguments.

But you are speaking about Symfony 2.3, and unfortunately I don't think it is possible to do what you want without arguments. Here are some example on how to pass the current route / the URL as an argument of your controller.

1) Passing the URL :

```
{{ 
   render(controller('AdminDashboardBundle:Template:sidebar', {
      'url': app.request.requesturi 
   })) 
}}
```

2) Passing the route :

```
{{ 
   render(controller('AdminDashboardBundle:Template:sidebar', {
      'route': app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
      'route_params': app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')
   }))
}}
```

I know you want to use Symfony2.3 and this call without passing vars, I think that's simply not possible because of how work [scopes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html).